# selenium IDE thinks variable is a string instead of numeric

Tags: javascript, selenium

Hi I run to a problem while testing with selenium IDE, I need to increment a variable by two and instead of adding with the sum operator it adds strings.

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>n</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>in</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>nl</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.n!=storedVars.nl}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.n+storedVars.in}</td>
    <td>ne</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=numero</td>
    <td>${ne}</td>
</tr>
```

This leads to ne 192 instead of 21, Does anyone knows how to make it numerical addition?
PD:I've also tried assignment operators like storedVars.n+=2 and still operates as string and returns 192.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parseInt` function to make JS use strings as numbers and therefore add them together -

```
"1"+"1" = 11
parseInt(1)+ parseInt(1) = 2
```

(or `parseFloat()` if you want decimals)

(or the equivalent for whatever language you're writing in, I'm not clear on it from your code example)